# Deploy de sistema Laravel no Xampp

Tags: php, laravel

Boa tarde, tenho um sistema criado com *Laravel 5.5* e preciso subir ele com o *Xampp*. Se eu acesso via *Url* o diretório public do *Laravel*, funciona, porém preciso acessar a raiz do projeto. Criei um *.htaccess* e redirecionei porém ao tentar acesso tenho  erro 403, acesso negado.

**Montei o *.htaccess* da seguinte forma:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /sistemaLaravel/index.php [L]
```

Existem alguns projetos em Java e PHP hospedado dentro desse xampp no htdocs e funcionam perfeitamente.
Grato.

Comment: Não deveria ser: `/sistemaLaravel/public/`?

Comment: Já no servidor ou você está acessando da própria máquina?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testou assim:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sistemaLaravel

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```